# I cannot get NPM Start to work in Visual Code Studio; It gives me an errors I cannot understand

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, version-control, system-calls

Here's how it goes:

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\travel-react> npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\travel-react\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\xampp\htdocs\travel-react\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\18652\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-12-19T05_26_03_774Z-debug.log
```

How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: The error states that it does not find the package.json file in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a cache problem,try to delete those folders:
`C:\Users\`yourusername`\AppData\Roaming\npm\` and `C:\Users\`yourusername`\AppData\Roaming\npm\`

then try `npm install -g` and try again

Answer (score 0):

Create package.json file using npm init,
You can read more about package.json here,
https://medium.com/@krishankantsinghal/package-json-understanding-it-for-your-nodejs-reactjs-angularjs-or-any-javascript-app-which-use-5a18de90d33